# R determine sequence with dplyr using group by

Tags: r, dplyr

For the following data frame I would like to determine the sequence for column Drug grouped by ID
where the order should be based on column dat (earliest date shoud be the first in the sequence). In the initial df, some IDs have 1 row and some have more than 1 (in this case ID 1 & 5).

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8),
                 dat = seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-03-05"), by="weeks"),
                 drug = c("A","A","B","C","B","B","C","D","C","B"))
```

The desired output should be

```
  ID seq1
1  1  A,A
2  2    B
3  3    C
4  4    B
5  5  B,C
6  6    D
7  7    C
8  8    B
```

Comment: Group by ID, sort by date, then paste.

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(dat) %>%
  summarise(seq1 = paste0(drug, collapse = ","))
`

Comment: It's not fair, and officially discouraged at SO, to post full solutions in comments